# What would be an equivalent to the ratio of all odd numbers by all even numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence U defined by:

- $U_0 = 1$
- $U_{n+1} = U_{n}*(2n+1)/(2n+2)$

I am interested in how this sequence behaves near infinity.

As the terms are multiplied, each step, by $(2n+1)/(2n+2)$, which is in the $]0,1[$ interval, it should converge, probably toward 0 although I don't know how to prove that. Knowing the limit is not enough though: I would ideally be able to have a polynomial equivalent for how fast it converges (or an other simple equivalent if polynomial is not possible).

Comment: With natural log and $0<t<1,  \log( 1 - t ) = t + \frac{t^2}{2} + smaller$  by Taylor  series. What if $t = 1/(2n+2)$

Comment: The title is not very good math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Robert Shore's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4263850/16078) is probably the best way to think about this problem. But just to give a very hands-on approach: note that
$$
\bigg( \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \bigg/ \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n+2}} \biggr)^2 = \frac{(2n+1)^2(n+2)}{(2n+2)^2(n+1)} = 1 - \frac{3n+2}{4(n+1)^3} < 1
$$
for all $n\ge0$. In particular, $\displaystyle\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} < \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n+2}}$ always, and so
$$
0 < \prod_{n=0}^N \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} < \sqrt{\prod_{n=0}^N \frac{n+1}{n+2}} = \sqrt{\frac1{N+2}},
$$
which is enough to imply that $\displaystyle\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$ diverges to $0$.

(Indeed, changing the $\displaystyle\frac{n+1}{n+2}$ to $\displaystyle\frac{n}{n+1}$ produces the lower bound $\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac1{4(N+1)}}$ for the partial product, so $N^{-1/2}$ is the right order of decay.)

Comment: Nice!
I still have a few details to solve after that but they seem trivial. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You want $\prod (1-\frac{1}{2n+2})$.  This converges to a non-zero number if and only if $\sum \ln (1-\frac{1}{2n+2})$ converges.  But the Taylor series for $\ln (1-x)$ shows us that this sum is greater (in absolute value) than $\frac 12$ of the harmonic series, so the product diverges to $0$.